# Bash, display processes in specific folder

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I need to display processes, that are running in specific folder.
For example, there are folders "**TEST**" and "**RUN**". **3** sql files are running from **TEST**, and **2** from **RUN**. So when I use command **ps xa**, I can see all processes, runned from **TEST** and **RUN** together. What I want is to see processes, runned only from **TEST** folder, so only **3**. Any commands, solutions to do this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94357/find-out-current-working-directory-of-a-running-process

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof` for this.

`lsof | grep '/path/of/RUN'`.

If you want to include both RUN and TEST in same command

`lsof | grep -E "/path/of/RUN|/path/of/TEST"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `fuser` to see which processes have particular files open; or, on Linux, examine the `/proc/12345/cwd` symlink for each of the candidate processes (replace `12345` with the process id of each).

```
fuser TEST/*.sql

for proc in /proc/[1-9]*; do
    readlink "$proc/cwd" | grep -q TEST && echo "$proc"
done
```

The latter is not portable to other U*xes,  though some may offer similar facilities.